# Json.NET: Deserialization with list of objects

Tags: c#, json, list, json.net, deserialization

I am processing JSON responses (displayed below) from a service on my Windows Phone 7 client. I am using Json.NET to deserialize them into an object, which contains List of products.

But after I deserialize, when I looked into my serviceresponse object, I can see a list of 2 products. But when I expand the product object, the fields under product (Name, ExpiryDate... etc ) are all null.

I guess my problem is with the way I have defined my serviceresponse class. Can someone help me to resolve the issue and get the correct output.

My deserialization code:

```
serviceresponse deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<serviceresponse>(json);
```

My Json response String:

```
{ "serviceresponse" : 

{ "company" : "ford", "success" : "Yes", "products" : [
  {"product" : 

      {
        "Name": "Product 1",
        "ExpiryDate": "\/Date(978048000000)\/",
        "Price": "99.95",
        "Sizes": "1"
      }
  },
  {"product" : 
      {
        "Name": "Product 2",
        "ExpiryDate": "\/Date(1248998400000)\/",
        "Price": "12.50",
        "Sizes": "1"
      }
  }
], "callbackformore" : "No", "message" : "1" 

    } 
}
```

My serviceresponse class:

```
[DataContract]
public class serviceresponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public String company;
    [DataMember]
    public String success;
    [DataMember]
    public List<product> products;
    [DataMember]
    public String callbackformore;
    [DataMember]
    public String message;
}

[DataContract]
public class product
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Name;
    [DataMember]
    public String ExpiryDate;
    [DataMember]
    public String Price;
    [DataMember]
    public String Sizes;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this. I found this awesome tool [Jsonclassgenerator](http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/). It could generate C# classes for the input Json string. Then I opened the generated class and found how the classes are laid out. And modified my Datacontract accordingly.

In my case, I have to create another data contract surrounding the list of objects. So it should be like this.

```
[DataContract]
public class serviceresponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public String company;
    [DataMember]
    public String success;
    [DataMember]
    public List<product> products;
    [DataMember]
    public String callbackformore;
    [DataMember]
    public String message;
}
[DataContract]
public class product
{
    [DataMember(Name = "product")]
    public product2 _product;
}
[DataContract(Name = "product")]
public class product2
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Name;
    [DataMember]
    public String ExpiryDate;
    [DataMember]
    public String Price;
    [DataMember]
    public String Sizes;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `"product"` object names from your json, as this is just array with no named items.

```
{ "serviceresponse" : 

{ "company" : "ford", "success" : "Yes", "products" : [
  {
    "Name": "Product 1",
    "ExpiryDate": "\/Date(978048000000)\/",
    "Price": "99.95",
    "Sizes": "1"
  },      
  {
    "Name": "Product 2",
    "ExpiryDate": "\/Date(1248998400000)\/",
    "Price": "12.50",
    "Sizes": "1"
  }
], "callbackformore" : "No", "message" : "1" 

} 

}
```

Comment: Json.NET is adding the extra product class so that it knows how to deserialize to List<T>. If the list wasn't a generic type, the product you're referring to should disappear.

Comment: Is there anything that I can do without modifying the response message that I receive from the server?

Comment: @fabraham you could write something like this: `public class ProductContainer{public product product;}` to wrap your original products, and replace products field in `serviceresponse` like this: `public List<ProductContainer> products;`. Though I'm not sure this is the best solution, perhaps there are some deserialization flags, or something.

Comment: Using Product[] rather than List<Product> would certainly change the deserialization.